# Does Outlook 2011 allow attachments through mailto link?

Tags: bash, email, outlook, mailto, outlook-2011

I am trying to start composing a new message via `mailto` on OS X. I have set my default email client to be Outlook, so I can open up Outlook with a preconfigured message like so:

```
open 'mailto:SomeEmail@example.com?subject=hey&body=how are you doing'
```

but I want to also be able to use the `mailto` link to add an attachment to the preconfigured message. I have tried the following:

```
open 'mailto:SomeEmail@example.com?subject=hey&body=how are you doing&attachment=/Users/myName/Desktop/testFile.rtf'
```

but when Outlook opens, there is no attachment. I have read that whether or not attachments are allowed with `mailto` links depends on the client. Does anyone know if Outlook 2011 allows for this type of attachment?

Comment: I wonder if `attachment=file:///path/to/file` would work.

Comment: @glennjackman unfortunately that still isn't working for me. Thanks for advice though.

Answer (score 4):

Specifying attachments is not part of the [IETF `mailto:` URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068), though individual clients may support it in one way or another.

I'm not sure if [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) applies to Outlook 2011 (OSX), but if it does, then what you are trying to do is probably not possible with [mailto](/questions/tagged/mailto).

Alternatively, I assume that since you are using the `open` command at the command-line, then you will be open to other command-line/shell-script methods of achieving this.  One such way is to redirect an [applescript](/questions/tagged/applescript) in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)  [here-document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents) to [`osascript`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html):

```
$ osascript <<EOF
> tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
>     set myMsg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"hey", content:"how are you doing"}
>     make new recipient at myMsg with properties {email address:{address:"SomeEmail@example.com"}}
>     make new attachment at myMsg with properties {file:"/Users/myName/Desktop/testFile.rtf"}
>     open myMsg
> end tell
> EOF
$
```

Comment: I think this has to be the first time I have blatantly combined GNU, Apple-proprietary and MS-proprietary elements all working together in one answer ;-)

Comment: upvoting for effort. Didn't use osascript, but thanks for help.